Emitting unoptimized LLVM IR that 'opt' can transform
For static analysis purposes, I have a custom pass that I've registered into opt, however that custom pass requires some analysis and transformation passes.
To avoid Clang accidentally deleting or optimizing out the information I'm trying to analyze (e.g. value of function call's argument, load/store of a variable, ...), up until this point I was passing -O0 to Clang when emitting IR:
./clang foo.cpp -O0 -g3 -S -emit-llvm

However, when doing so Clang adds the noinline and optnone attributes to the functions, which prevents opt's transformation passes from doing anything. Understandably so, but still an issue in my circumstances.
Attempt 1
Up until this point, to work around this I was running a modified version of LLVM where the hasOptNone() method within llvm/IR/Functions.h always returned false, however that's obviously way overkill, and if possible I'd rather use vanilla Clang rather than messing with applying custom patches to LLVM.
Attempt 2
So here's my new attempt which enables optimizations but disables LLVM passes. It seems to work okay so far and the functions no longer have the noinline and optnone attributes, but now I'm not sure that the LLVM IR still follows the C++ standard's requirements (e.g. evaluating integer-constant-expressions when required to do so).
./clang foo.cpp -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -O3 -g3 -S -emit-llvm

Attempt 3
Another option that I would be okay with would be to run, before any other pass, a new custom pass which would simply remove these two attributes from everything, but in that case I'd remove these attributes from functions that have an actual __attribute__((noinline)) or the like, which I need to keep for my static analysis (e.g. to attempt to find function call argument values).
Questions
So my questions:

Do you have any better suggestion?
Regarding attempt #2, is there a way to have Clang emit actual -O0 code without adding the attributes to functions that don't have an explicit __attribute__ in the source? Or should -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -O3 be enough?
Regarding attempt #3, is there a way I could somehow identify my own functions so that the custom pass that removes attributes doesn't do so for mine?

